# running python modules in python launcher

Tags: python

I made a small game of pong in python and the idle I used was eclipse and all of it works (for the most part). But when I try to run the game through the python launcher rather than eclipse it crashes immediately. In fact any program that I make in eclipse won't run outside of it. I'm basically trying to figure out how I will be able to put my game on other peoples computers.

What is the problem?

Comment: Based on the information you provided, the problem is that any program you make in eclipse won't run outside of it.

Comment: This is a very broad question with little context of the actual issue faced. Please provide some detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is too generic, but I'll answer as to what is the most likely issue: your environment.
Fundamentally, eclipse does NOT use the pythonpath set in your environment. It has its own internal configuration (python interpreter, pythonpath, etc...).
So make sure your environment variables match your eclipse configuration. That is likely to solve your problem.